# Build framework IOS OpenCV 3.1.0.2 failed on MAC (OS X El Capitan)

Tags: ios, macos, opencv

I would like to use OpenCV 3.1.0.2 (the latest one) with Xcode 7.2.1.

I downloaded the OpenCv then as I did with OpenCV 2.4.11 before, I used the following command to generate the opencv2.framework:

```
python opencv-3.1.0\ 2/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios
```

But after a while, my build failed. Here the error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/nameUser/openCV/ios/build/arm64-iPhoneOS/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/gzlib.o 3rdparty/zlib/gzlib.c normal arm64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/nameUser/openCV/ios/build/arm64-iPhoneOS/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/gzread.o 3rdparty/zlib/gzread.c normal arm64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
============================================================
ERROR: Command '['xcodebuild', 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0', 'ARCHS=arm64', '-sdk', 'iphoneos', '-configuration', 'Release', '-parallelizeTargets', '-jobs', '4', '-target', 'ALL_BUILD', 'build']' returned non-zero exit status 65
============================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_framework.py", line 87, in build
    self._build(outdir)
  File "build_framework.py", line 81, in _build
    self.buildOne(t[0], t[1], mainBD, cmake_flags)
  File "build_framework.py", line 139, in buildOne
    execute(buildcmd + ["-target", "ALL_BUILD", "build"], cwd = builddir)
  File "build_framework.py", line 34, in execute
    retcode = check_call(cmd, cwd = cwd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '['xcodebuild', 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0', 'ARCHS=arm64', '-sdk', 'iphoneos', '-configuration', 'Release', '-parallelizeTargets', '-jobs', '4', '-target', 'ALL_BUILD', 'build']' returned non-zero exit status 65
```

Before posting here, I searched on the internet but I couldn't find any solution for this problem. I don't even know what does this error means.

Can anyone help me please ?
Thank

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly same with my case but you can try two ways:

1. Did you install cmake?

   - If not, install that.
2. Did you check your python version?

   - Because Python 3 and 2 are much 
     different, you should check that.

In my case, 2.x is working. If you installed 2.x and 3.x both, the command "python" means 3. so you should use "python2.x" command.

I'm not sure you can understand what I'm writing(bc my english skill is not good..) but I hope It helps you to solve the problem!

Comment: cmake and python2. but don't soved. :<